# SHP, SHX and DBF files became empty (zero byte) overnight on QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-2.4, dbf

This literally happened overnight. I was working on a shapefile in QGIS 2.4 last  night but my files (SHP, SHX and DBF) all become zero byte this morning.

If this has happened to anyone before, how should I go about solving this problem?

QGIS was installed on Ubuntu 12.04 in VMWare Workstation. Host machine runs on Windows. The only thing special I did was running a apt-get update at the same time.

Comment: That's really strange. What backups do you have to restore from? You left them in edit mode during the update? Might be a file system or operating system problem... More info might help.

Comment: Yes, I think I did leave it in edit mode during update. I don't have a backup. There's still a few rows of data left in DBF when I viewed it using text editor. 
Is there still hope?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a GIS issue.  More like something a virus would do.